# My require line in application.css.scss isn't working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I added "jquery_mobile_rails" to my Gemfile and did bundle install. Then I added the following lines to my application.css.scss file:

```
//=require jquery.mobile
```

However when I run 'bundle exec rails s' and start my app I get this error:

```
couldn't find file 'jquery.mobile'
  (in /Users/Me/Development/ruby/myapp/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss:1)
```

I loaded the Rails app console and looked at the assets path config:

```
 Rails.application.config.assets.paths
```

I get an array of paths which includes my Gemfile path with the jquery_mobile_rails gem and inside the vendor/assets/javascript I see the file jquery.mobile.js.

So why can't I include this in my application.css.scss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mistakenly added the line for javascript(application.js) in the application.css . Please add the following line to your application.css.scss

```
*= require jquery.mobile
```

Comment: Thank you, my syntax could also be used for compiled scss files (which I have since switched to)